# Extract rows if max-min in that row fulfill certain conditions

Tags: unix, awk, max, min

I have a tab-delimited file with the lines as:

```
chr1 1001 + KEEP 0.5 0.3 0.06 0.4 0.2 0.3 0.5
chr1 40004 + KEEP 0.93 0.2 0.6 0.25 0.8 NA NA
chr2 140004 + KEEP 0.03 0.02 0.06 0.05 0.08 NA 0.01
chr2 455235504 - KEEP NA 0.12 0.67 0.51 0.8 NA NA
chr3 5004 + KEEP 0.53 0.52 NA 0.5 NA 0.54 NA
..
```

I want to calculate the difference between the max and min on each line from the 5th column onwards, and extract the rows in which this (max-min) difference is equal or more than 0.1. So for example with the input given above, I should get:

```
chr1 1001 + KEEP 0.5 0.3 0.06 0.4 0.2 0.3 0.5
chr1 40004 + KEEP 0.93 0.2 0.6 0.25 0.8 NA NA
chr2 455235504 - KEEP NA 0.12 0.67 0.51 0.8 NA NA
..
```

How can I use awk to do this for about a few million lines per file?

Currently I'm trying out

```
awk '{min=max=$5; 
      for(i=5;i<=67;i++){
        if($i<min) min=$i;
        if($i>max) max=$i
      }
      print min,max}' test.txt
```

Comment: Hint: your code should have a loop like `for (i = 5; i <= NF; i++)` in it to loop through the columns and find the min/max.

Comment: Currently I'm trying out `awk '{min=max=$5; for(i=5;i<=11;i++){if($i<min) min=$i; if($i>max) max=$i} print min,max}' test.txt` to test whether `awk` can extract the max and min values. Then I'm thinking of how to manipulate it to give me the difference. Then I'll figure out how to set the given condition.

Comment: That said, the first line counts NA as 0, so I'm stuck on it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly you're just missing the test for whether the difference between `min` and `max` is more than your threshold. You should also use `NF` as the limit in the `for` loop, not hard-code a number like `67`.

```
awk '{min=max=$5; 
      for(i=6;i<=NF;i++){
        if ($i == "NA") continue;
        if (min == "NA" || $i<min) min=$i;
        if (max == "NA" || $i>max) max=$i
      }
      if ((max - min) > .1) print}' test.txt
```

I also added a check for `NA`, it skips those values.

Comment: Brilliant! That `== "NA"` bit was exactly what I needed. Awesome

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python solution which has no extra dependencies and should run virtually anywhere:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    strings = line.rstrip().split(' ')[4:]
    numbers = [float(string) for string in strings if string != 'NA']
    if max(numbers) - min(numbers) >= 0.1:
        print line,
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk way

```
awk '{min=max=x;for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){min=min!~/./||$i<min?$i:min;max=$i+0>max?$i:max}}
      max-min>=.1' file
```

This sets min and max to 0 at the start of each line.
Then loops from 5 to the number of fields in the line.
Then if min is not set or is less than $i set it to $i.
If max is more than $i, set it to $i
The $i+0 is to remove the "NA" which will then be set to 0.
Print lines where max minus min is more than or equal to .1.

This answer assumes max will always be above 0.

If max can be less than 0

```
     awk '{min=max=x
     for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){min=min!~/./||$i<min?$i:min
     $i!="NA"&&max=max!~/./||$i>max?$i:max}
     } max-min>=.1' file
```

Comment: I've seen it used a few times and can't quite wrap my head around why people do it so could you explain what the benefit is of setting a variable to some other variable that hasn't been populated (`var=x`) rather than setting it explicitly to the null string (`var=""`)? I always waste my time looking for "x" to see what it's value is and then feel like pounding the keyboard when I finally convince myself it's an unset variable being used in place of `""`. If it did set min and max to zero as stated in the comments, then that would be the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @EdMorton sorry, i don't know why i do it, guess its just a bad habit. Also i forgot to edit the comments after editing the script, so apologies again for the misinformation.

Comment: You're not alone, I've seen other people do it to, I honestly just can't understand why so I think there must be SOME benefit that I'm just not getting... Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    min = max = ""
    for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i == $i+0) {
            min = ( (min == "") || ($i < min) ? $i : min)
            max = ( (max == "") || ($i > max) ? $i : max)
        }
    }
}
(max - min) >= 0.1

$ awk -f tst.awk file
chr1 1001 + KEEP 0.5 0.3 0.06 0.4 0.2 0.3 0.5
chr1 40004 + KEEP 0.93 0.2 0.6 0.25 0.8 NA NA
chr2 455235504 - KEEP NA 0.12 0.67 0.51 0.8 NA NA
```

The test for `$i == $i+0` will only be true when `$i` is a number so it will discard cases where `$i` is `"NA"` or any other non-numeric value.

As an enhancement, you could easily tweak it to report lines that have no numeric values if you like:

```
{
    min = max = ""
    for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i == $i+0) {
            min = ( (min == "") || ($i < min) ? $i : min)
            max = ( (max == "") || ($i > max) ? $i : max)
        }
    }
}
min == "" { printf "ERROR[%d]: \"%s\" has no numeric values.\n", NR, $0 | "cat>&2" }
(max - min) >= 0.1
```